# Swift - observe static member change, without using property observer

Tags: ios, swift, observer-pattern, observers

I've got next situation: from the viewDidAppear I have to call the specific function ( to change the view controller to another one) when the special condition applied ( static member changes to True, another class access this static property and send True once the certain conditions apply)

If I do it like this with property observer:

```
//this is property of load view controller
  static var isFilled: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isFilled == true {
            print("data is Filled")
                //load view controller - my present VC, which I want to switch
                var loadVC = LoadViewController()
             loadVC.changeViewController(vc: loadVC )
```

This is changeViewController function:

```
        func changeViewController(vc: UIViewController) {
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil )

            //main view controller - controller, which i want to Go to

            var mainViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            vc.present(mainViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

It'll throw an error **attempt to present viewcontroller whose view is not in the window hierarchy**

And, it's performed inside LoadViewController class

As I understand, the only way to avoid this error is to call the function from the **viewDidApper**, which can't be used in this scenario, because i have to call it only when condition applied. ***Are there any alternatives to perform that w/o using property observer?***

I'm sure there are multiple ways to perform this, and there are might be misconceptions from my side. I'm pretty fresh developer, and completely new to Swift. All the suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: `loadVC` never gets presented

Comment: @nighttalker Hey, thanks for the rapid reply.  I will add more details to the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use NotifiationCenter by registering a notification and then calling it whenever you want to update something, like "updateConversations" in a chat app. For example in viewDidLoad(), register your notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateConversations(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateConversations"), object: nil)
```

Add this function into the class:

```
@objc func updateConversations(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let id = notification.userInfo?["id"] as? Int,
        let message = notification.userInfo?["message"] as? String {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Use the notification from anywhere in your app:

```
let info = ["id" : 1234, "message" : "I almost went outside today."]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateConversationsList"), object: self, userInfo: info)
```

Comment: Happy to help @AndreyFr! Please accept and upvote my answer when you get a chance.